# Setting cors via az webapp - Missing Access-Control-Allow-Credentials options

Tags: azure, cors, azure-web-app-service

I have a devops pipeline set up to clear cors and add them again like so to make the build the definer of all settings:

```sh
az webapp cors remove-g XXX -n XXX -a
call az webapp cors add  -g XXX -n XXX -a %1
```

Which works fine. It clears all previously added cors and adds the paramaterised value to cors. However the check box in azure for `Enable Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` gets unchecked everytime. I cannot find anywhere in the azure docs how to set this value:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp/cors?view=azure-cli-latest#az-webapp-cors-add

Does anyone know how to set this to true on set use of `az webapp cors add` ?

Answer (score 6):

At this moment you cannot use `az webapp cors add` to enable Access-Control-Allow-Credentials. It was [already suggested to add a supportCredential parameter](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/9514), but the issue was closed.

However, you can use another command to enable it:

```
az resource update --name web --resource-group <resource_group> \
  --namespace Microsoft.Web --resource-type config \
  --parent sites/<app_name> --set properties.cors.supportCredentials=true
```

Read more on [App Service documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-rest-api#enable-cors).

Comment: This is the only answer that works in a single command line. The github issue you linked suggests using `azwebapp config set --generic-configurations ...` but it appears to have issues unless you use a separate json configuration file.

Comment: I'm planning to send a PR in Azure CLI to include `--supportCredentials true` to `az webapp cors`. Let's hope that got merged